# Composite functions for positive integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x,f(x) ,a, b$ be positive integers. Furthermore, if $a>b$ then $f(a)>f(b)$. Now, if $f(f(x))=x^2+2$, then what is $f(3)$?

My solution:
If $f(a)>f(b) $ for $a>b$ then $f$ is an increasing function. This means it is a one to one function. Now here $f(f(x))$ is quadratic function then if we restrict ourselves for $x\geq0$ then it is onto also, hence it is bijective and its domain will be $[0,\infty)$ for that condition. 
Now, $f(f(3))=11$.
So, $f(3)=f^{-1}(11)$

From here on I am not able to think more. How inverse f is going to come? Or, is there any other ways to do?

Answer (score 1):

First I'll point out a problem with your proposed solution: $f$ being a quadratic function does not necessarily mean it is an onto function, take for instance $f(x) = x^2$ which fails to hit $2$.

Consider the value of $f(1)$. Clearly $f(1) = 1$ leads to a contradiction, and $f(1) \geq 3$ gives $3 = f(f(1)) \geq f(3) > f(1) \geq 3$, a contradiction also. Thus $f(1) = 2$, and so $f(2) = 3$ giving $f(3) = f(f(2)) = 2^2 + 2 = 6$.

Comment: Why $f(x) = 2x$ is not injective? Could you give an example of an increasing function that is not injective?

Comment: You said: "being an increasing function does not necessarily mean it is a one to one function,  take for instance f(x)=2x". Now, your first claim "being an increasing function does not necessarily mean it is a one to one function" is true only if you define "increasing" in a non-strict way, which is not the meaning given in the OP. Moreover, the function $f(x) = 2x$ is increasing (even strictly) and one-to-one. I use "one-to-one" and "injective" as synonymous.

Comment: [Injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) means "one-to-one". [Surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) means "onto".

Comment: Ah, I was always taught "one-to-one" refers specifically to bijective functions. I'll edit to remove confusion.

Comment: Sorry Mr. Mehta, but I am not able to understand your thought process. Can you please explain it in more detail? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @jayant98 Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: The part when when you assumed f(1)>=3. Sorry for delayed reply.

Comment: I wanted to find the value of $f(1)$, and I showed it must be $2$ by contradiction. Specifically, $f(1) = 1$ cannot work, and $f(1) \geq 3$ cannot work since it leads to $3 > 3$.

Comment: Oh! Now I understood.